# Iis it possible to store all events in central RDBMS DB in micro service architecture using axon 3.3.3?

Tags: axon

I would like to understand an Axon feature.
Currently, we are developing an application using microservice architecture.
We want to store all service events in a central RDBMS database, like for example PostgreSQL.

Is it possible to use such a store?

We have used the below configuration to store events in same domain DB:

```java
@Bean
public AggregateFactory<UserAggregate> userAggregateFactory() {
    SpringPrototypeAggregateFactory<UserAggregate> aggregateFactory = 
        new SpringPrototypeAggregateFactory<>();
    aggregateFactory.setPrototypeBeanName("userAggregate");
    return aggregateFactory;
}
```

Now we want to store events in a central Event Store DB, not with domain DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the `AggregateFactory` within any Axon application does not define where or how your events are stored at all.
I instead suggest to read the [Event Bus & Event Store](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-bus-and-event-store) section of the Axon Framework reference guide on the matter to explain how you can achieve this.

The short answer to your question is by the way *yes*, you can have a single Event Store backed by a RDBMS, like PostgreSQL, to store all your events in.
Between duplicated instances of a given application it is actually highly recommended to use the same storage location.

As soon as you are going to span different [Bounded Context's](https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/bounded-contexts-with-axon), I would suggest to define different Event Stores per context though.

Concluding, you are using an **old** version of Axon Framework. 
I would highly recommend to move the at least the latest Axon 3 release, being 3.4.3, but ideally you start using 4.1.2. 
Note that there is no active development taking place on Axon 3 any more, hence the suggestion.

Comment: Glad to have been of help @NarasimhaA